# How to insert a value from a list in excel sheet using nodeJs and excelJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

Have created an application using nodejs(npm excelJs), which writes the data to an excel sheet(which includes validations and automatic calculations).

for example:I have a column called "type" in my excel which have a validation of: {
type: 'list',
formulae: [
'"A,B,C,D"',
'0'
],
allowBlank: true,
showInputMessage: true,
showErrorMessage: true,
errorStyle: 'stop'
}

Based on the "type" the total amount will be calculated.

But when i try to insert the value to "type" using the code below WorkSheet.getRow(row).findCell(cell + 3).value = "A";
the value is just inserting but the total value is not calculating.

what am i missing here?can anyone explain how to select a value from a list in a excel column using the node?

Answer (score 0):

To add a formula to a cell you must use the formula property.

```
cpyWorkSheet.getRow(row).findCell(cell + 3).value = { formula: "Support(L1_L2)" };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. have tried the above but getting like this in the cell #NAME? and when i double clicked on the cell am getting "=support(l1_l2)"

Comment: FYI, the excel sheet already have a formula i.e { type: 'list', formulae: [ '"A,B,C,D"', '0' ], allowBlank: true, showInputMessage: true, showErrorMessage: true, errorStyle: 'stop' }. I just need to insert a value to that particular cell which have above validation.